# NET::ERR_SSL_OBSOLETE_VERSION with Chrome

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, nginx-config

I have a node app hosted in AWS ec2 and installed letsencrypt certificates. When I am trying to access the API, it is giving error

***Connection - obsolete connection settings
The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.0, ECDHE_RSA, and AES_256_CBC with HMAC-SHA1.
TLS 1.0 is obsolete. Enable TLS 1.2 or later.
AES_256_CBC is obsolete. Enable an AES-GCM-based cipher suite.***

SSL Certificates shows correctly  from letsencrypt

I have infact set TLS 1.2 AES-GCM-based cipher in config file. my nginx version is

nginx version: nginx/1.16.1
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017

Any pointers?

here is my nginx.conf file snippet

```
http {
include         /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type    application/octet-stream;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;

keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;



server {
    listen       80;
listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    ssl_certificate      /opt/ssl/cacert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /opt/ssl/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols SSLv2 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    #ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    #charset koi8-r;

   
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    server_name  aws.qureme.co.in;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/aws.qureme.co.in/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/aws.qureme.co.in/privkey.pem;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;


}
```

}

Comment: Likely the snippet you show does not tell the full truth, i.e. there must be more. The server `aws.qureme.co.in` is clearly only responding with TLS 1.0. Also note that you try to configure TLS 1.3 although the OpenSSL version you use does not support TLS 1.3 - it is only supported since OpenSSL 1.1.1. Thus check any other parts of the configuration (i.e. not only this specific server section) for different TLS configuration. Check also the error log of nginx for any problems.

Comment: Thanks Steffen . Is it enough I change the openssl library alone or any thing to do with certificate itself. ? ( I am ok even with TLS 1.2 also, though). There is another server configuration, which could be the cultprit as you mentioned. will try that out

Comment: TLS versions have nothing to do with the certificate. Changing the OpenSSL version alone is not sufficient since a) nginx must actually use this version (i.e. build against it) and b) there are likely settings in part of the nginx configuration you did not show, which cause it to use TLS 1.0.

Comment: Hi Steffen, As you said, I have one more server block, which could have made it to set to TLS 1.1.  Iam modifying the Query with full spec. There I have removed SSL3. #ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;  Now, from Safari it is working. but Chrome shows another Error. "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

Comment: You cannot have different ssl protocols set for the same IP address on different virtual hosts. Also ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR is too unspecific, there should be more details on this error. And why do you want to support the terrible SSLv2, which isn't likely supported by the OpenSSL anyway? And did you already look into the servers error log?

Comment: Steffen, So grateful to you. I have set the same protocol for IP address as well as domain name. And also the ciphors too. Now it is working on both Safari and Chrom

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was when I set a different protocol and ciphers for 2 server Block( one for IP Address and another phone for domain name.

**THANKS A LOT FOR STEFFEN ULLRICH** for the input. Here is the modifed spec

```
server {
        listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        ssl_certificate      /opt/ssl/cacert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /opt/ssl/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
      
    }

    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2;
        server_name  aws.qureme.co.in;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/aws.qureme.co.in/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/aws.qureme.co.in/privkey.pem;

        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;


    }
```